# jQuery mobile - checkbox without a label

Tags: jquery-mobile

Has anyone written any extensions or know a way to have jQM create a checkbox without a label?

When you don't include a label jQM doesn't format it, it just leaves it as a regular checkbox.  I have looked at the code and think there is a way to do it but don't want to mess with jQM base code if I don't have to.

I think this should be in the base code because you shouldn't have to have a label with a checkbox.  Any thoughts on this would be great.

Nick

Comment: Couldn't you make the label an empty string "" or a non-breaking space "&nbsp;" (alt+160)

Comment: No because then it looks horrible, I was hoping someone had done this before and had some css or javascript that would fix it.  I am going to post a request at github for it to be implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQM Has another layout option, would this work?

- http://jsfiddle.net/R372c/3/

HTML

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-6" id="checkbox-6" class="custom" />
        <label for="checkbox-6">b</label>

        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-7" id="checkbox-7" class="custom" />
        <label for="checkbox-7"><em>i</em></label>

        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-8" id="checkbox-8" class="custom" />
        <label for="checkbox-8">u</label>    
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

Docs:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/forms/checkboxes/ (Bottom of the page)

> **Horizontal toggle sets** 
> Checkboxes can also be used for grouped button
>   sets where more than one button can be selected at once, such as the
>   bold, italic and underline button group seen in word processors. To
>   make a horizontal button set, add the data-type="horizontal" to the
>   fieldset.
>
> `<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">` The
>   framework will float the labels so they sit side-by-side on a line,
>   hide the checkbox icons and only round the left and right edges of the
>   group.

Comment: I saw this and I tried it but it didn't work for what I needed so I created my own CSS.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: ninedoors, why haven't you shared your solution with us? What CSS did you use to solve the problem? The usefulness of this post will be greatly enhanced by some explanation of how you fixed thie issue. Do you mean you abandoned jQuery Mobile for the checkbox, or did you modify the jQM CSS?

Answer (score 1):

Just a follow up on this, since I keep returning here with my JQM checkbox woes! An excellent little article here by one Rick Luna:

[JQM Checkboxes Without Labels](http://rickluna.com/wp/2012/10/jquery-mobile-checkboxes-without-labels/)

Answer (score 0):

JQM needs the label for accessibility, but there are ways to hide it - just add the appropriate class, as [specified in the documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/docs-forms.html)

Either

```
  <label for="username" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Username:</label>
  <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" placeholder="Username"/>
```

or

```
  <div data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-hide-label">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="" placeholder="Username"/>
  </div>
```

depending on your layout choice!

Hope this helps...

Comment: I ended up just creating my own css to make a checkbox on its own.  Thanks for the suggestions though